# Adding jinja template dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I have a jinja template that is the only content inside a set of div tags.

```
<div id="section0">
    {% include 'temppage.html' %}
</div>
```

When I press a button, I want to replace everything between the tags with something else. I was hoping to replace it with another jinja template, "{% include 'realpage.html' %}", but first I am unsure of how to replace the entire section, instead of just replacing a single word. Second, can I even add a jinja template dynamically, or do I need replace it with a string with the contents of the file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As glls said, replacing the content can be used with,

```
document.getElementById("section0").innerHTML = "something";
```

As for adding a jinja template dynamically, you need to replace the innerHTML with a multi-line string of the wanted jinja template, with is used with backticks, "`". So it would look like,

```
document.getElementById("section0").innerHTML = `{% include 'realpage.html' %}`;
```

The template is executed when the page loads (which is unavoidable as far as I'm aware), so when inspecting the html of the live page, the multi-line string will contain whatever is in the file you are including.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JS framework (such as Angular, React...) in order to achieve this...I am assuming you are trying to build a single page app?

Otherwise, you will have to rely more on Javascript in order to change the HTML under you div depending on what you click. For example, if you have button 1, 2, 3. Each rendering a different HTML template upon clicking.

Example (using jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-class', function() {
    document.getElementById("section0").innerHTML = "something";
});
```

fyi: "something" can be an html structure.

Comment: The website will be a single page, yes. Just tested the jquery example to change what was inside the div, and that worked, so thank you for that part. Do you know how I might use a jinja template dynamically? As in where "something" is, instead have "{% include 'realpage.html' %}"

Comment: not that I know of, Jinja is mostly for generating/rendering html on page load