# Javascript with socket.io improve current implementation

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, socket.io

So I have been going through a tutorial for rethinkdb and sockets to make a chat app. I have it done but i'm thinking the way I made it on the javascript side is very inefficient and could be improved. 
Any ideas on how to actually improve this?

This is the html part (with jinja2 but that doesn't matter

```
<ul id="chat-list" class="collection">
    {% for chat in chats %}
        <li class="collection-item highlight">
          <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3">
            <div class="lighten-5">
              <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                <div class="col s2 border_right">
                    <p class="black-text wrap center-align">
                        {{ chat.name }}
                    </p>
                    <div class="center-align">
                        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPjOOT32EQQ7nrf8X964O7ULV_GNy6lkwK8yrsHojZ4BsNsDHw" alt="" class="circle max_image hoverable">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12">
                  <span class="black-text wrap">
                    {{ chat.message }}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      <!--<li class="collection-item"><p class="s10">{{ chat.name }} - {{ chat.message }}</p></li>-->
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is the javascript part

```
<script>

var chatForm = document.getElementById('chat-form');
var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
var messageInput = document.getElementById('message');
var chatList = document.getElementById('chat-list');

var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
socket.on('new_chat', function(data) {
  chatList.innerHTML = '<li class="collection-item highlight>"> \
          <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3"> \
            <div class="lighten-5"> \
              <div class="row valign-wrapper"> \
                <div class="col s2 border_right"> \
                    <p class="black-text wrap center-align">'
                        + data.new_val.name +
                    '</p> \
                    <div class="center-align"> \
                        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPjOOT32EQQ7nrf8X964O7ULV_GNy6lkwK8yrsHojZ4BsNsDHw" alt="" class="circle max_image hoverable"> <!-- notice the "circle" class --> \
                    </div> \
                </div> \
                <div class="col s12"> \
                  <span class="black-text wrap">'
                    + data.new_val.message +
                  '</span> \
                </div> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
          </div> \
        </li>' + chatList.innerHTML;
});

chatForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var request = axios.post('/chats/', {
    name: nameInput.value,
    message: messageInput.value
  });
  request.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  messageInput.value = "";
});
</script>
```

I would wanna know how to improve this, especially the javascript part as i find it very hard to modify the html in the js there in the current shape.

Comment: Not very familiar, but could you extract your chat html as a template and include it dynamically upon `new_chat` event? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068358/5842628

Comment: that's basically what i've been trying to figure out